# Make toggle menu button sticky

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sticky

Im editing my WP back-end, and I cant find support for making my menu button scroll with my page.  I can make a *menu bar* scroll with the page, but this button is a bit different.  it is a little box that expands to show menu options when clicked.

how do I make the unexpanded menu button scroll with the page?  below is my header.php code that contains the same div button classes that I found when I inspected the html in firefox

`<button class = "menu-toggle x"></button>)`

here's the header.php code (sorry it looks weird--was having trouble getting it read on here)

```
<button class="menu-toggle x">

            <span class="lines"></span>

            <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'intergalactic' ); ?></span>

        </button>

        <div class="slide-menu">

            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">

                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

            <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>

                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social', 'depth' => 1, 'link_before' =>

'<span class="screen-reader-text">', 'link_after' => '</span>', 'container_class' => 'social-links' )
 ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {

                get_sidebar();

            } ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pascale,

This is something that is generally handled in the front end with CSS, very simply too...

```
.menu-toggle{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px; /* or whatever is best for your design */
    right:0px; /* or whatever is best for your design */
    z-index: 999; /* this assures that it stays in front of all other content*/
}
```